# Cramer Rule Over Finite Field

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

> Let $A=\pmatrix{4&2\\ 0&1},\ b=\pmatrix{5\\ 3}$ and $A\pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2}=b$ over the field $\mathbb Z_7$.
>
> What is $x_1$?

So we need to calculate $$x_1=\frac{\det(A_1)}{\det(A)}$$

which is $\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}
5&2\\
3&1
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
4&2\\
0&1
\end{vmatrix}}=\dfrac{6}{4}$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: If you're working over a finite field $F_p$ except $F_2$, then 4 has a multiplicative inverse. Multiply 3 by that inverse and then mod by 7

Comment: @user2566092 so it is $\frac{3}{4}=2*3=6$ mod(7)

Comment: Yep, you got it. I wanted to let you figure out the inverse and it looks like an answer has been posted that confirms your calculation.

Comment: @gbox Why is $\begin{vmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \equiv 3 \mod 7$?

Comment: @Paolo I didn't even notice that, but yeah it looks like there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: I think it should be $\begin{vmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \equiv 6 \pmod 7$. Therefore, $x_1 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

Comment: @Paolo thanks, my mistake but isn't it ($5*1)-(2*3)=5-6=-1=6$ mod(7) or you refer to $\mathbb{z_7}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Comment: @gbox I think it is $-1 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$, because $-1 - 6 = -7$, which is divisible by $7$.

Comment: @Paolo sorry didn't see $x_1=5$ and not the determinant

Answer (score 2):

$$
4\cdot 2 \equiv 1\pmod 7.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $3$ we get
$$
4\cdot 6 \equiv 3 \pmod 7.
$$
So
$$
4 \div 3 = 6\text{ in }\mathbb Z_7.
$$